# getting field value from an object in query result list

Tags: grails, groovy

I am getting a resultset from a query which has users object like this

> column summap=[[6, gra.Users : 1], [2, gra.Users: 7]]

where 1,7 are the ids of the user from Users entity

I want to get employeeid from this id how do I do that?

I tried Users.get(it[1]).employeeid but it says cannot get property employeeid on null object.
How do I get employeeid?

Regards
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gra.Users : 1` looks like the default `toString()` output for a domain class, so I'm guessing that the 2nd values in each array are `Users` instances, not ids. So it'd be something like

```
def results = executeQuery(...) // [[6, gra.Users : 1], [2, gra.Users: 7]]
def employeeIds = results.collect { it[1].employeeid }
```

Comment: thats absolutely right Burt..just tried it before and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Users.get(it[1].id).employeeid
```